# A train to catch - game breaking glitch?

Tags: borderlands-2

So I am halfway through *A Train to Catch* but when I get to Tina she says she has no jobs for me and my quest log hasn't updated. I am unable to get past this point. Here is screenshot:

[image]

How can I proceed?

Comment: Looking at [this video](https://youtu.be/SmUpXhG0OL4?t=9m2s), it looks like immediately after completing the "Meet Tina" task, it should have switched that out to the "Find badonkadonks (0/2)" task. So you may have a glitch there.

Comment: If you're playing the Steam version (might be doable on console?), the first thing I would do in a situation like this is quit without saving and check your save folder for a backup. There's always one backup of your save file, from one save before the current save. if that was before you encountered this glitch, you may be able to salvage your progress by deleting the main save game and renaming the backup file to take the place of the main save. If not, you can look into use Gibbed's Borderlands 2 save editor to undo this mission progress, then redo it in-game and hopefully avoid the glitch.

Comment: I vaguely remember having to wait for Tina to walk back to her workshop before I could talk to her and advance some quest or another.

Comment: I always found Borderlands to be pretty good when it comes to digging itself out of holes. I'd imagine simply closing the session and then continuing will fix the problem, although it's likely you've probably done that already by now.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is to try to make a new character, the "Train to catch" mission is not that far in the story line but it depends on what your playing on.  If you are playing on steam try exiting the game or signing out of your steam account. if your playing on and xbox 360 or one try to delete the save file for the game then re downloading it, or shut down your xbox in console setting. this is just my guess.